# Why GET request is not working in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean

```
 const express = require('express');
 const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
 const app = express();
 const Student = require('../models/students');
 require('dotenv').config();
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 const cors = require('cors');
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.static('./dist/mean-stack-application'));


 mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
   useCreateIndex: true,
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useFindAndModify: false
 }).then(() => {
    console.log("Connection is Successful");
 }).catch((e) => {
    console.log("No Connection");
 });


 app.get("/studentData", async( req,res ) => {
    try{
       const getStudentsData = await Student.find();
       console.log(getStudentsData);
       res.send(getStudentsData);
   }catch(e){
      res.send(e);
   }
 });

 app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Connection is setup at ${PORT}`);
 });
```

Angular Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestoService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 readonly baseUrl = 'https://mean-curd-app.herokuapp.com';

 readonly url = '/studentData';


 getList(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${this.url}`)
 }
}
```

It's working on localhost 3000 but when I host this MEAN stack app on Heroku then I got error msg which is status code 304. Connection is successful but something is wrong that's why I got this error msg.

GitHub Source Code Link : https://github.com/SwapnilVedpathak-sv/mean-stack-application
Heroku Hosted Link : https://mean-curd-app.herokuapp.com

Comment: The '304' status is not an error . It says that data was not changed since last request .
You can check and update values of "If-None-Match" or a "If-Modified-Since" headers to get 200 anyways .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here.  A 304 is not an error.  It is how a web server set up for efficiency works.  When a cooperating client asks for the same resource they've previously asked for in a "conditional GET request" and that resource has not changed since they previously cached it, then the server sends them a 304.  The client can then use their cached version.

For further info see this [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304).

> The HTTP 304 Not Modified client redirection response code indicates that there is no need to retransmit the requested resources. It is an implicit redirection to a cached resource. This happens when the request method is safe, like a GET or a HEAD request, or when the request is conditional and uses a If-None-Match or a If-Modified-Since header.

You may be seeing it on Heroku because that's where you're configured for a production deployment so these types of optimizations are enabled.

Comment: Why GET request is not working in Node.js when hosted on Heroku but works on Local ?

Comment: How can I resolve that error give me the solution if you have.

Comment: @SwapnilVedpathak - This is NOT an error.  Chances are the configuration on Heroku is set up for more "production" optimizations as this is an expected optimization for a web server.  You'd have to explain why this is causing a problem as this is proper operation of a production-level web server.  It should be present in conjunction with a client that expects and knows what to do with a 304.

Comment: @SwapnilVedpathak - See various Express optimizations and settings: [Performance Best Practices](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html) and [`app.set()` configuration optiions](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html).